# How should I ask the staff if I need to exchange my electronic tickets for physical ones in order to get in a theme park

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I bought a ticket from a theme park's website. I am not sure if this ticket along is sufficient to let me get in since it has a bar code on it, or I need to go to some kiosks and show my ticket to get a physical ticket.

Can anyone teach help me regarding the matter? I know I might get my message across just by saying what I wrote on the title of the question but I'd really like to learn some authentic English.

Comment: Why do you think that what you wrote in the title is (not) good?

Comment: @virolino because I am learning English so I don't know if it is good or not.

Comment: Your original question is almost perfectly fine.  "Do I need to exchange my e-tickets for physical ones, {in order} to get **into** the park?"   You can drop the words *in order*